# Datetime passed with AngularJs to ASP.NET MVC action does change according to server timezone

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I pass an array of dates using AngularJs to an ASP.NET MVC action and while debugging I can see a strange behaviour.

For example, the array in AngularJS is like this

```
["2017-11-24T20:00:00-05:00", "2017-11-25T00:00:00-05:00"]
```

But on the server side it arrives like this

```
['11/25/2017 2:00:00 AM', '11/25/2017 6:00:00 AM']
```

This happens only when I change the timezone of my laptop to `UTC-05:00 Eastern Time (US & Canada)`.

My real timezone is `UTC+1:00 Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest...`. The reason why I changed the timezone is because the server is located in USA or Canada.

I guess when I submit those dates from here they change at the server side and do not show correctly. I think it might be a problem in model binder or something.

Is there any way to tell the model binder to ignore timezone and parse the string to the exact date I sent with the request?

For example date `2017-11-24T20:00:00-05:00` -> `11/25/2017 08:00:00 PM` in C# etc

Answer (score 0):

try to parse date and convert to specific time zone.

```
//set variables
var centralTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
var ISODateStyle = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind;

//parse date
var date = DateTime.Parse(inputDate, null, ISODateStyle);
// change time zone
var newDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, centralTimeZone);
```

In javascript, get ISO date

```
 var dt =  someDateVar.toISOString();
```

The above code is for CST and ISO date format. Change date format and time zone accordingly

Comment: I cant convert to a specific timezone since the client might be in different timezones. I want to save the date in the users computer timezone

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj "I want to save the date in the users computer timezone". Not a good approach. Then your data will be impossible to query or slice by date since it's all in different timezones. Save the data in a single timezone (the timezone your server is set to is a sensible one, or maybe UTC if you prefer). Then when you display it to the user, present it to them in their local timezone

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj - I have similar case, this is the reason used ISO date format and at server saved in one time zone.  as highlighted by ADyson it will be a problem for you in future.  add a generic method detect user time zone show date/time accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can set this using the `DateParseHandling` and `DateTimeZoneHandling` configs on `JsonSerializerSettings` (see: [Newtonsoft JsonSerializerSettings Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm))

For dotnet core, you can configure it in `Startup.cs`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(config =>
    {
        // This prevents the json serializer from parsing dates
        config.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
        // This changes how the timezone is converted - RoundtripKind keeps the timezone that was provided and doesn't convert it
        config.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind;
    });
}
```

For older asp.net versions you can configure it a similar way in  `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
};
```